# Capitalize the last two letters in a string

Tags: python, string, uppercase

My attempt:

```
location = "new orleans, la"
location = location[:-1].upper()
```

The last letter gets cut off.  I just want the state (2-letter abbreviation) capitalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code preserves all but the last two characters in their original state.  To that, it appends the final two characters in upper case.

```
location = "new orleans, la"
location = location[0:-2] + location[-2:].upper()
```

You got cut off because that's exactly what you told it to do: take all characters up to -- but not including -- the last one, convert them *all* to upper-case, and make that the new value of `location`.

Result:

```
'new orleans, LA'
```

Comment: I see the simplicity of your answer now.